# create a flat file from "oracle backup" files

Tags: oracle, database-backups, database-administration, flat-file, informatica

I have a scenario wherein I need to refer to the oracle db backup files (.bkp/.dmp). I cannot touch Oracle db due to the constraints posed by the live running application . I do not know much about the nature of these backup files hence asking this question. Are these files encrypted or zipped? Are they segregated tablespace wise? I know for sure that the ones available to me are not flat files.

Is there any oracle option or utility --or-- a unix command/utility by which I can convert the oracle db backup file to a flat file? I am planning to import the backup files from oracle server to my drive.

Also is there any ETL tool like Informatica which can do the job?

Comment: The only (really: the only) tool that can read a dump file is `impdp` (or `imp` if you were using the deprecated `exp` tool). So the *only* option you have is to restore that dump file into *some* server and create the flat files from there. There is no other option.

Comment: Just to add to @a_horse_with_no_name - that assumes that whoever generated these files use the `exp` or `expdp` utility to create them.  That's a reasonable inference based on the .dmp extension.  But it's just an inference-- someone may have used any number of tools to generate files in any number of formats and simply named the file with a .bkp or .dmp extension.  You would probably need to find out exactly how the files were created before we could be sure exactly what options, if any, you have.